# How does loss of single drive influence 4k random performance of RAID 1 array?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, sata, raid-1

Here is one explanation of the benefits of RAID 1:

"As different disks can seek on different data, it [RAID 1] has **up to 2x the random read IOPS but the same** 1x (or slightly lower, due to overhead) **random write IOPS**."

source: https://serverfault.com/a/869954/352288

Is this correct?

That would mean the random read would get equal to a single disk, but the random write could even be faster in degraded mode because of the absence of the overhead. Is this even possible?

Suppose we are using a standard SATA-III 6 disk (WD VelociRaptor) on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, in theory.  Different drives have different characteristics, which affect performance.  Then there is the overhead, you mentioned.  But more importantly, this is assuming the RAID 1 array is made up two physical disks.  While not common, you can mirror three or more disks.  This gives you the most redundancy at the highest cost of storage.  If the mirror contained more disks, the numbers would obviously be better.